# Does the use of a global variable within a function cause a local copy to be created

Tags: c++, c, function, memory, global-variables

Unfortunately I can't find anything on the subject although I can't believe this question hasn't been asked before.

When I use a global variable inside a function, is a local copy of the variable created as with a passed argument or is the global variable accessed directly?
Does it even make sense to define a global variable as a parameter of a function using the reference declarator `&` or as a pointer `*`?

PS: I know that global variables are a bad practice, but I'm programming for a microcontroller where it sometimes make sense to use global variables.

Comment: 1) No. C++ does not create "local copies" of global variables. You access them directly. 2) Variables can be global or they can be function parameters. Not both.

Comment: Global variables are not copied unless you copy them.  That said, avoid using global variables, they make the code harder to reason about and make the potential for bugs increase.

Comment: Prefer to tag one programming language. C does not have references, so do not tag it if your code contains references.

Comment: C and C++ are distinct languages. Very rarely should you tag both, unless you are asking about their differences/similarities or interaction.

Comment: You can't "define a global variable as a parameter of a function", unless you mean something else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Globals are not copied when used in a function.  There are used directly.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x;

void foo1()
{
    x=2;
}

void foo2()
{
    printf("%d\n", x);
}

int main()
{
    foo1();
    foo2();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2
```

The first function modifies `x`, and the second reads the modified `x` and prints it.

If globals were in fact copied in each function, it would be impossible to modify them, and the above code would instead print `0`.

Comment: Thx for the clarification. Now that I think about it this was a dumb question. Otherwise a global variable couldn't be changed inside the main function.

Answer (score 2):

> When I use a global variable inside a function, is a local copy of the variable created as with a passed argument or is the global variable accessed directly?

The global variable is used directly. A local copy is not made.

> Does it even make sense to define a global variable as a parameter of a function using the reference declarator & or as a pointer *?

Yes, there are some situations in which this may make sense. For example, if you have several global variables and have a function which writes to these global variables, but not always to the same global variable(s), then it may make sense to pass a pointer or a reference to a global variable.

In the code block below, I have created a simple example program, which defines three global variables `a`, `b` and `c` and first swaps the values of the variables `a` and `b` and then the values of the variables `b` and `c`. For both swaps, the same function can be used, because the function takes as function arguments a pointer to each global variable that is to be swapped.

It is necessary for the global variables to be passed by pointer (or in C++ by reference) instead of by value, because otherwise, the function would swap the local function arguments instead of the global variables.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 5;
int b = 3;
int c = 2;

void swap( int *first, int *second )
{
    int temp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = temp;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf(
        "Before swapping,\n"
        "the global variables have the following values:\n"
        "a = %d\nb = %d\nc = %d\n\n",
        a, b, c
    );

    swap( &a, &b );

    printf(
        "After swapping the values of a and b,\n"
        "the global variables have the following values:\n"
        "a = %d\nb = %d\nc = %d\n\n",
        a, b, c
    );

    swap( &b, &c );

    printf(
        "After also swapping the values of b and c,\n"
        "the global variables have the following values:\n"
        "a = %d\nb = %d\nc = %d\n\n",
        a, b, c
    );
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
Before swapping,
the global variables have the following values:
a = 5
b = 3
c = 2

After swapping the values of a and b,
the global variables have the following values:
a = 3
b = 5
c = 2

After also swapping the values of b and c,
the global variables have the following values:
a = 3
b = 2
c = 5
```

Since you tagged the question with both C and C++ (which should generally not be done), I gave an example that is compatible with both C and C++. In C++, one would generally use a reference instead of a pointer, and one would use `std::cout` instead of `printf`.

Comment: Re “Global variables are used directly. A copy is not made.”: That is not the rule. What is happening here is simply this: An object used via its name is used directly. A value used via a parameter is a copy of the argument value. That’s it. It ultimately has nothing to do with whether an object or its name is global, file scope, block scope, other scope, static, automatic, temporary, or other. The name of the object means the object. The name of a parameter means the parameter. If there are multiple instances of a name, the innermost one whose scope has started and not ended is the one used.

Comment: But if I would define the parameters of this function not as a pointer or a reference but just like `void swap(int first, int second);` And then pass two of the global variables to the function, would this create local copies or just use the global variables directly?

Comment: @shyney: That would create local copies. The local copies would get swapped, but the original variables would not get swapped, so that the `swap` function would effectively do nothing.